# Running PowerShell Startup (Logon) Scripts Using GPO

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, gpo

There are two user accounts, one is Administrator; another is normal user.

1. AD Domain: Windows Server 2019 with GPO
2. Client: Windows 10: (A) Use Administrator to login the AD
   Domain: GPO works well and add registry to HKLM; (B) Use normal User
   to login the AD Domain: GPO something went wrong and failed to add
   registry to HKLM.

The (B) situation: I copy the PowerShell to Windows 10 Client and perform the script, I got the error message:

> New-Item : Access to the registry key
> 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\OneDrive' is denied.
> At C:\Users\alanb\Desktop\Handling_OneDrive_REG.ps1:47 char:58
>
> - ... HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft" | New-Item -Name "OneDrive" -Force
> - ```
>                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (HKEY_LOCAL_MACH...rosoft\OneDrive:S     tring) [New-Item],
>     UnauthorizedAccessException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.PowerShel
>     l.Commands.NewItemCommand   New-ItemProperty : Cannot find path
>     'HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\OneDrive'  because it does not
>     exist. At C:\Users\alanb\Desktop\Handling_OneDrive_REG.ps1:50 char:5
> - ```
>   New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\OneDriv ...
>   ```
> - ```
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKLM:\Software...rosoft\OneDrive:Str     ing) [New-ItemProperty],
>     ItemNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemProp     ertyCommand
>     New-ItemProperty : Cannot find path
>     'HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\OneDrive'  because it does not
>     exist. At C:\Users\alanb\Desktop\Handling_OneDrive_REG.ps1:51 char:5
> - ```
>   New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\OneDriv ...
>   ```
> - ```
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKLM:\Software...rosoft\OneDrive:Str     ing) [New-ItemProperty],
>     ItemNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemProp     ertyCommand
>     New-ItemProperty : Cannot find path
>     'HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\OneDrive'  because it does not
>     exist. At C:\Users\alanb\Desktop\Handling_OneDrive_REG.ps1:52 char:5
> - ```
>   New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\OneDriv ...
>   ```
> - ```
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>   ```
>
>   - CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (HKLM:\Software...rosoft\OneDrive:Str     ing) [New-ItemProperty],
>     ItemNotFoundException
>   - FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemProp     ertyCommand

I also setup some settings as the following:

1. the NTFS “Read & Execute” permissions for the Domain Computers group
   in the ps1 file permissions
2. setup Computer Configuration -> Administrative Templates -> System -> Group Policy section. Enable the “Configure Logon Script Delay” policy and specify a delay in minutes before starting the logon
   scripts (sufficient to complete the initialization and load all necessary services). --> 1-2 minutes.
3. The security settings for running the PowerShell script can be configured via the “Turn On Script Execution” policy (in the GPO Computer Configuration section -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Windows PowerShell) --> Allow all scripts (unrestricted)

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO.  'Access denied' is most likely a simple registry permissions issue -- nothing to do with the script, file system, or GPO.  Consider this: If regular users can create local machine registry keys and update values under HKLM:\Software\Policies, then what's to stop them from randomly making system-wide 'policy' changes at any time?  Meaning: Don't try making this a logon script for standard users; or, always run it as an administrator only.

Comment: Hi Harvey, I hv solved it out already. Originally I set it under User Configuration, now I change it to Computer Configuration in GPO. It works well. To be honest, I also have no idea why the settings cannot be configured in USER CONFIGURATION.